# OAuth1 Authentication in Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, oauth

I am trying to connect my drupal using OAuth Token. 
I am able to successfully do it using PostMan with OAuth1 Authentication set as header.
In my javascript app, I am using Fetch for get request, the issue is how to you add the header. 
In php one can use *GuzzleHttp\Subscriber\Oauth\Oauth1;  Class* ([Ref](https://gist.github.com/juampynr/caf2959c77306f7a299b))

But how to do this in my JS App? what library can I use for generating proper header compatible with OAuth using Consumer Secret and Client Key

Sample JS Code

```
return fetch('http://d8.epicureans.in/node/1?_format=json', {'mode': 'no-cors',
method: 'get',
headers: {},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using oauth-1.0a 
Check implementatiom on
https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a/issues/35